# Why the JQuery script is not applied is Asp.net MVC blazor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am trying to build a new application using Blazor and I am facing a weird issue. The "onload" jquery scripts are not applied even though the breakpoint is fired.
Let's take an example, here is my setup:

_Host.cshtml:

```
@page "/"
@namespace DentalOffice.Pages
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="description" content="Dento - Dentist &amp; Medical HTML Template">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>DentalOffice</title>
    <!-- Favicon -->
    <link rel="icon" href="./img/core-img/favicon.ico">

    <!-- Core Stylesheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
    <!-- jQuery js -->
    <script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Popper js -->
    <script src="/js/popper.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap js -->
    <script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- All js -->
    <script src="/js/dento.bundle.js"></script>
    <!-- Active js -->
    <script src="/js/default-assets/active.js"></script>
    <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Index.razor:

```
  @page "/"
  <!-- Preloader -->
  <div id="preloader">
    <div class="preload-content">
      <div id="dento-load"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

active.js:

```
(function($) {
  var dento_window = $(window);

  // *******************************
  // :: 1.0 Preloader Active Code
  // *******************************

      dento_window.on('load', function() {
        $('#preloader').fadeOut('1000', function() {
          $(this).remove();
          });
        });
      })(jQuery);
```

If I run this page as plain HTML it works as expected and the loader disappears. Inside Blazor component is behaving very strange. If I set a breakpoint in active.js on line: **$(this).remove();**, the breakpoint is hit but the change is not updated on the UI (the preloader is not removed).
[image]

However, if I manually trigger remove from the console like this ($('#preloader').remove()), it works.

What could be wrong here?

Comment: have you tried printing "this" object

Comment: Hi @ArpitBansal, yes, this is the correct DOM element : 
<div id="preloader" style="display: none;">
    <div class="preload-content">
      <div id="dento-load"></div>
    </div>
  </div> 
as you can see the "display" is none, but still, the content is on the screen. If I check the html in developer tools, the style attribute is not there. I guess, somehow Blazor is not able to push back into Dom the updates from Javascript

Comment: Blazor updates the browser from a virtual DOM it builds using its own components. If you use JQuery or other tools to manipulate the browser DOM directly, it can result in conflicts and one or the other being overwritten or ignored. You can use them on the same page but overlaps will usually result in this kind of behaviour.

Comment: I found a better explanation from SS: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/15830#issuecomment-403517253

Comment: The best approach is to do it in Blazor: https://blazorfiddle.com/s/zasqydr3